# Problems installing bcrypt-nodejs on Windows machine

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, bcrypt

I am having some problems installing bcrypt-nodejs on Windows machine, not bcrypt but bcrypt-nodejs which is a different dependency.

I get the output below in the command line after doing `npm install bcrypt-node.js`

```
    C:\web_dev_root_folder\facerecognitionbrain>npm install bcrypt-nodejs
npm WARN ts-pnp@1.0.1 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ bcrypt-nodejs@0.0.3
updated 1 package and audited 36348 packages in 31.525s
found 63 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

And when I go ahead and try to run my script by doing `npm start` I get:

```
> facerecognitionbrain-api@1.0.0 start C:\web_dev_root_folder\facerecognitionbrain-api
> nodemon server.js

[nodemon] 1.18.10
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'bcrypt-nodejs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\web_dev_root_folder\facerecognitionbrain-api\server.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Any solution to this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that you need to install it globally with the -g flag?  Or use the -s flag to save it to your project dependencies?

Comment: I tried that, it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: try using this library, easy to install easy to use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-inzi

Answer (score 0):

Did you run your `npm install` in the wrong directory?

Looks like you did the `npm install` in `C:\web_dev_root_folder\facerecognitionbrain`, but you are requiring it in `C:\web_dev_root_folder\facerecognitionbrain-api\server.js` which is in a different directory.

Comment: Oh God, you are right, I don't know how I did such a silly mistake ! Thanks for pointing it out.
I thought that the package had some issues in Windows but it was just an error on my side. Thank you so much for taking your time to figure this out.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help